# Fresnel lens safe viewing distance

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, lenses, laboratory-safety

I work for a summer camp, and we have a [Fresnel lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens) that is roughly 18in x 24in. I'm writing a safety document for the device, and am attempting to find out the minimum safe viewing distance without eye protection. We use it mostly as a novel experience. A participant that is next to the device is required to wear a welding helmet.

What I know:

- The focal point will get up to ~1800F, which will melt aluminum,
  zinc, silver, or glass. Will 'cut' thin wood.
- 12 oz. of water will boil in 80 seconds
- [The direct normal solar irradiance during July, in California](https://www.nrel.gov/gis/solar.html), is ~7.5 kWh/m<sup>2</sup>/day

It's been a while since I did any optics problems (several years)...though there was a time that this was an easy problem. To resolve this question, I would need two things:

1. The 'amount' of light that will damage a human eye
2. A formula for the amount of light at different distances from a point source

Comment: So those inches are about 0.25 m². Solar irradiance is about 1 kW/m², which would be 250 watt. Temperature about 1000 C. I cannot see danger in watching this.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that this website should not be giving any safety advice except for the "don't do it" type. If the calculations given as answers to this query are wrong that could have dire consequences.